# Use an icon in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath Title (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the neccessary code for the swipe Actions and they display properly, but I am having a hard time getting icons instead of the title text.

I have attempted using [FontAwesome for iOS](https://github.com/leberwurstsaft/FontAwesome-for-iOS), but  it isn't a label it is a title attribute...

I attempted using

`deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"sample")!)`

But I don't see how that will ever display right as it tiles the image, if I make the image the correct size then wont it be wrong on a different screen size?

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage(named:"sample")!` automatically takes the @1, @2 and @3 variant of an image. So if you create the images in the correct size it will work.

However, keep in mind that putting an image as background is not the way Apple designed it to work (and it may not be working in the future). If you want total control, find a library which does exactly what you want like [MCSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell) or build something like that yourself.